# Paragraph with no indent after a figure (or other floats)

Tags: floats, koma-script, paragraphs, noindent

is there a way to print a paragraph which follows a figure without an indent automatically (when using koma script)? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[
DIV=11
]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setparsizes{5.5mm}{0pt}{0pt plus 1fil}

\begin{document}
\chapter{MyChapter}
\blindtext %the first par. of this chapter has no indent. Correct.

\blindtext %the second par. has an indent. Correct.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \rule{2cm}{2cm}
    \caption{MyFigure} 
\end{figure}

\blindtext %this par. is printed after a figure and should have no indent.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: AFAIK not with floats, because floats can float. If you'd use the non-floating environment `figure-` instead, you could just remove the paragraph between the figure and the following text.

Comment: To elaborate: if TeX decides to float your figure and move it elsewhere, what should happen with the indentation?

Comment: Add \noindent just after figure.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Dangerous if the float floats to another place … In such a case it is IMHO better to not allow floating.

Comment: I know. But on the koma script level there could be the information right there that above a certain paragraph is a figure placed. Or is this something only the kernel knows? So there could be a switch to the document class which says: NoIndentAfterFloat=yes :-) At the moment it seems that there is no. But I was just wondering about this.

Comment: @hjele Where to output a float is decided in the LaTeX output routine. So, no, there isn't any kind of `NoIndentAfterFloat`. BTW: If there would be any, it could also be hard to recognize the paragraph. So I'm even not sure, whether this would be a good idea. But if you like, see my first comment and use a non-float.

Comment: @cabohah thanks for explaining the routine and yes, your hint on the non-float environment helps.